# How to notate a diagonal matrix with a offset

Tags: matrices

Is there standard notation for a diagonal matrix with a $d$ offset.

for example, when $d = 1$, we have:

M = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

And,this definition 'a diagonal matrix with a $d$ offset' seems inaccurate, is there standard definition or name for it?

Comment: This specific case can be called "tridiagonal." I've also seen "banded."

Comment: One matrix, two matrices. There is no such thing as a matrice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the notation of band matrix in [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix)